# Blender 2.81: How do I mirror a collection of objects, instead of a single object, across the center pivot?

Tags: mirror, collections

[image]

So Object Modifiers only work on objects, or is there some way to make them apply to a Collection as well?

Comment: I haven't heard of that, but if you give all your objects the same Mirror modifier with an empty as Mirror Object it will give what you want...

Comment: I know this thread is old, but perhaps a collection instance could be used here :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the origin to the center of your object, duplicate the object you want to mirror (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and rotate the object $180°$ (<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>, 180)

Answer (score 0):

Create a *Collection Instance* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and set the scale to $-1$.